# Programmatically increase font size for NSAlert

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I can't seem to increase the font size of my NSAlert - or even the size of the entire box.

```
else if array[arraycount].containsString("Error: error.") {
   let myPopup: NSAlert = NSAlert()
   myPopup.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.WarningAlertStyle
   myPopup.addButtonWithTitle("I've Called!")
   myPopup.informativeText = "Sorry, we weren't able to that. Please Call Support 1(800)234-4567 ext: 12345"
   myPopup.runModal()
   let app = NSRunningApplication.currentApplication()                           
   app.activateWithOptions(.ActivateIgnoringOtherApps)
 }
```

This is my current code which works fine, but I will be running my OS X application on an iMac and the text looks really small. I was wanting to increase the point size programmatically, but I can't find anything about it in Swift. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The documentation of NSAlert is in English, did you try to read it? Did you see `messageText`?

Comment: I actually wanted to set my font size, not just use a predefined one. I wasn't able to find anything to do that, even though I can read English. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `informativeText`, that's really small.

Instead, set `messageText`. That's much bigger, and bold.

Even better, set both, so more important information is big and bold and less important information is small.

```
myPopup.messageText = "Sorry, we weren't able to that."
myPopup.informativeText = "Please Call Support 1(800)234-4567 ext: 12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option to use accessoryView in the alert.

```
let accessory = NSTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
let attributes : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]
let accessoryText = "Some more readable text"
let accessoryAttributedText = NSAttributedString(string: accessoryText, attributes: attributes)
accessory.textStorage!.setAttributedString(accessoryAttributedText)
accessory.isEditable = false
accessory.drawsBackground = false
alert.accessoryView = accessory
```

Comment: The OP accepted an answer long ago, but you can also set properties of the default text fields via their subview in the alert window’s contentView.